# Field doesn't exist in Gatsby GraphQL + WordPress (but works locally)

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WordPress, Gatsby + GraphQL to build a blog. Yesterday everything worked and I got the featured_media field but today it just stopped working and I'm getting this error telling me the that it can't query the field. (WordPress site is hosted on Bluehost).

Error

`wordpress__wp_media fetched : 0`

`Cannot query field "featured_media" on type "wordpress__POST"`

Inside GraphiQL there is indeed no featured_media field but when I use my local Wordpress website it works correctly.

gatsby-config.js file

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
      options: {
        baseUrl: process.env.WORDPRESS_URL,
        protocol: 'http',
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: false,
        auth: {}
      },
    },
```

GraphQL query: ( this works locally )

```
      featured_media {
        alt_text
        localFile {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 600, quality: 100) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              presentationWidth
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I don't have much experience making a blog with Gatsby + WordPress.

What I tried:

- I added the `Better REST API Featured Images` plugin to my WordPress site but then I'm getting back only the `source_url`.
- I deleted the WordPress site on Bluehost and created a new one and after that you can edit or add posts but if you delete any posts it will throw the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you trying to remove the cache with `gatsby clean` when you change the sourceURL ?

Not sure that's the problem but this option solve most of mine when Gatsby don't find data in my GraphQL when I change the source url.

Hope that help you!

Answer (score 1):

This looks related to a persisting issue in that `gatsby-source-wordpress` plugin, described here: [Troubleshooting for gatsby-source-wordpress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-wordpress#graphql-error---unknown-field-localfile-on-type-image-field)

Basically some images are coupled with a certain `post_parent` in Wordpress and can become inaccessible when their `post_parent` object becomes inaccessible.

The suggested solution is to edit the `post_parent` manually in your Wordpress database and to set it to `0` so that changes on the `post_parent` can't affect the accessibility of your image.

There is also a respecting [change request for Wordpress](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41445).